# Rails on Linux Mint 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux-mint

I have installed ruby via rvm on Mint 11 no problem. Installed gems, ditto. Installed rails via gem install rails, and when I type `rails -v` it returns the correct version. Until I close that terminal and reopen a terminal. When I do that and type `rails -v` I get the message

```
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install rails
```

If I then type

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p180 --default
```

and then type `rails -v` I again get the correct version...until I close the terminal.

I should add that I have added a path statement to my `.bashrc` pointing to the `1.9.2-p180` directory in my `.rvm` directory.

Typing `ruby -v` always returns the correct version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **.bashrc** file and add .rvm command

```
$ sudo touch ~/.bashrc

$ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

(Add line to .bashrc file)

```
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]  ; then source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ; fi
```

Logout and Login OR just update user profile from **.bashrc** with following command

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `which rails`. Maybe there is a link to a stub that gives you the note.
If that is the case calling the full path might help, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/rails`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this command to your `.profile` and reopening your shell:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Comment: Hans, I did have this line, but in my .bashrc. In any case, I blew away my .rvm and started completely over. This time, it appears that it took.

Answer (score 0):

Use project rvmrc files. You can see how to set this up here http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/best-practices/

That way you keep all your gems seperate for each project and it's dead simple to set up